# Distance between line formed by two points to every other point, for every possible line

Tags: python, iterator, permutation

Given a set of points, for all permutations of 2 points in the set, I want to calculate the total squared distance from every other point to the line defined by that pair.

Here's what I have so far:

```
import numpy as np
import itertools

def dist_point2line(a, b, c):
    return np.linalg.norm(np.cross(a-b, c-b))/np.linalg.norm(c-b)

points = np.array([(1,2), (2,3), (3,2), (0,4), (4,1), (3,3)])

pairs = itertools.permutations(points, 2)
distances = []
for (p2, p3) in pairs:
    total = 0
    for p1 in points:
        distance = dist_point2line(p1, p2, p3)
        total += distance*distance
    distances.append(total)
```

Problem is this currently also calculates the distance to p2 and p3, which are obviously zero. How can I make this more efficient?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of permuting your points, permute the indices of the points. The most inner loop can then iterate over each point index and exclude those that match any in the pair.

Something like:

```py
for pair in itertools.permutations(range(0, len(points)), 2):
    p1, p2 = points[pair, :]
    total = 0
    for other in range(0, len(points)):
        if other in pair:
            continue
        p3 = points[other]
        distance = dist_point2line(p1, p2, p3)
        total += distance**2
    distances.append(total)
```

Also to improve performance, you can initialize `distances` variable as a numpy array instead of a list:

```
n = len(points)
distances = np.zeros([n * (n-1)], dtype=np.float32)
```

You need to fix the code above a bit:

```py
for k, pair in enumerate(itertools.permutations(range(0, len(points)), 2)):
    total = 0
    ...
    distances[k] = total
```